# Changing the value in a list of vectors

Tags: clojure

I know that if I define team as:

```
(def team ["A" "B" "C" "D"])
```

I can change the value "B" to "E" by

```
(assoc team 1 "E") > ["A" "E" "C" "D"]
```

If I now have:

```
(def teams '(["A" "B" "C"] ["D" "E" "F"] ["G" "H" "I"]))
```

How would I change "B" to "1" for example

I thought you might have to use assoc-in but that doesn't seem to be working or maybe I made a mistake. I tried

```
(assoc-in teams [0 1] "1")
```

Answer (score 4):

You almost had it.  You are using a list, when you should be using a vector, to do what you want to do:

```
(def teams [["A" "B" "C"] ["D" "E" "F"] ["G" "H" "I"]])
```

The reason for this is that a vector is an associative structure (i.e., it is a structure with key/value pairs).  It's like a map, which is associative, except that for a vector, the key is the index in the vector.  Contrast this with a list, which cannot be indexed into, and must be iterated to obtain an element.  So, to use ***assoc***-in, you need to use an associative structure, and a list won't do.

The error you got was:  `clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Associative`, and a look at the source shows this:

[`IPersistentList`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IPersistentList.java) gives:

```
public interface IPersistentList extends Sequential, IPersistentStack
```

Contrast with the `Associative` [`IPersistentVector`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IPersistentVector.java):

```
public interface IPersistentVector extends Associative, Sequential, ...
```