# update or assoc a list rather than a vector

Tags: clojure

Updating a vector works fine:

```
(update [{:idx :a} {:idx :b}] 1 (fn [_] {:idx "Hi"}))
;; => [{:idx :a} {:idx "Hi"}]
```

However trying to do the same thing with a list does not work:

```
(update '({:idx :a} {:idx :b}) 1 (fn [_] {:idx "Hi"}))
;; => ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Associative  clojure.lang.RT.assoc (RT.java:807)
```

Exactly the same problem exists for `assoc`.

I would like to do update and overwrite operations on lazy types rather than vectors. What is the underlying issue here, and is there a way I can get around it?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of a question I answered a few weeks ago:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020226/changing-the-value-in-a-list-of-vectors/41020950#41020950   I will echo the sentiments of Scott below regarding a lazy structure.  The benefit of a lazy structure comes in not having to realize it, but in updating it, you realize it, making it not lazy.  So, I'm not sure what you want to actually achieve.  An associative structure by definition cannot be lazy, because there must be an association from each key to each value.

Comment: A list does have order, so theoretically it could realise a key at the same time as realising the value. But then it would become associative, which it is not. That was my misunderstanding.

Comment: The problem I was trying to solve was http://adventofcode.com/2016/day/19. coredump's answer helped. In the end I used both a vector and a list to get a fast solution with very large collections: https://github.com/chrismurrph/advent-of-code/blob/master/dev/advent/nineteen.clj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own function, using `take` and `drop`:

```
(defn lupdate [list n function]
  (let [[head & tail] (drop n list)]
    (concat (take n list)
            (cons (function head) tail))))

user=> (lupdate '(a b c d e f g h) 4 str)
(a b c d "e" f g h)
```

With lazy sequences, that means that you will compute the `n` first values (but not the remaining ones, which after all is an important part of why we use lazy sequences). You have also to take into account space and time complexity (concat, etc.). But if you truly need to operate on lazy sequences, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying issue is that the `update` function works on associative structures, i.e. vectors and maps. Lists can't take a key as a function to look up a value.

```
user=> (associative? [])
true
user=> (associative? {})
true
user=> (associative? `())
false
```

`update` uses `get` behind the scenes to do its random access work.

> I would like to do update and overwrite operations on lazy types
>   rather than vectors

It's not clear what want to achieve here. You're correct that vectors aren't lazy, but if you wish to do random access operations on a collection then vectors are ideal for this scenario and lists aren't.

> and is there a way I can get around it?

Yes, but you still wouldn't be able to use the `update` function, and it doesn't look like there would be any benefit in doing so, in your case.

With a list you'd have to walk the list in order to access an index somewhere in the list - so in many cases you'd have to realise a great deal of the sequence even if it was lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Looking behind your question to the problem you are trying to solve:

You can use Clojure's sequence functions to construct a simple solution:

```
(defn elf [n]
  (loop [population (range 1 (inc n))]
    (if (<= (count population) 1)
      (first population)
      (let [survivors (->> population
                           (take-nth 2)
                           ((if (-> population count odd?) rest identity)))]
        (recur survivors)))))
```

For example,

```
(map (juxt identity elf) (range 1 8))
;([1 1] [2 1] [3 3] [4 1] [5 3] [6 5] [7 7])
```

This has complexity O(n). You can speed up `count` by passing the population count as a redundant argument in the loop, or by dumping the `population` and `survivors` into vectors. The sequence functions - `take-nth` and `rest` - are quite capable of doing the weeding.

I hope I got it right!